# When trying to List all the open tabs of the browser chrome i'm getting exception how can i solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I have a new project in Program.cs top i have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace List_all_opened_tabs_of_Firefox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> firefoxUrls = new List<string>();

            Process firefox = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0];
            AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(firefox.MainWindowHandle);
```

In the original instead "chrome" it was "firefox"
But i don't have firefox so i changed it to chrome and then i'm getting exception on the line:

```
AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(firefox.MainWindowHandle);
```

hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.
  Source=UIAutomationClient
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(IntPtr hwnd)
       at List_all_opened_tabs_of_Firefox.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\listopentabs\List all opened tabs of Firefox\List all opened tabs of Firefox\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Line 20 is:

```
AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(firefox.MainWindowHandle);
```

I'm trying to get a List of all opened tabs of chrome.
Downloaded and tried the source code from here:

[List Open Tabs](http://hintdesk.com/Web/Source/List%20all%20opened%20tabs%20of%20Firefox.zip)

Comment: I have now one chrome window in this window i have like 30 tabs opened.

Comment: fyi chrome is multi-processed. you might have gotten one of the tab processes.

Comment: from the docs: "A process has a main window associated with it only if the process has a graphical interface. If the associated process does not have a main window, the MainWindowHandle value is zero. The value is also zero for processes that have been hidden, that is, processes that are not visible in the taskbar. This can be the case for processes that appear as icons in the notification area, at the far right of the taskbar." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looking in task manager, there are 4 chrome processes running. So loop through them and pick the one that has a non-zero `MainWindowHandle`.

```
        var cp = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        IntPtr ww = IntPtr.Zero;
        foreach (var p in cp) {
            if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                ww = p.MainWindowHandle;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Loathing this will give me the main window of the chrome and i need to get a list of all the opened tabs of the chrome window. That's why i tried to use the AutomationElement i tried it from this small example: http://hintdesk.com/c-list-all-opened-tabs-of-firefox-with-uiautomation/ but no success i'm getting this exception and i'm not sure if the rest of the code is fine i downloaded the source there and changed it from "firefox" to "chrome"

Comment: The exception is pretty clear, the window handle you are passing in is `IntPtr.Zero`, which is NOT a valid reference to a window. You can always use Tools--> Spy++ to get the window handle and test it that way.